# getBounds() returns the same as getTransformedBounds() on a Shape() which has been scaled

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I'm having an issue with obj.getTransformedBounds() of a Shape().

The getBounds() method should return a rectangle (if it was set using setBounds()) which stores the x/y/w/h of the Shape() within its OWN coordinate space - it's real width & height with no transformations applied.

The getTransformedBounds() method should return a rectangle (again, if set by using setBounds()) which stores the x/y/w/y within its PARENT'S coordinate space - the shape's width & height with transformations applied.

Instead, I see getBounds() returning only the transformed bounds of a shape that has its scaleX and/or scaleY applied:
http://jsfiddle.net/W9Tb8/1/

```
var shape = new createjs.Shape();
shape.graphics = new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#f00").drawRect(0,0,100,100);
shape.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
shape.scaleX = shape.scaleY = 0.5;

console.log(shape.getBounds(), shape.getTransformedBounds()); // returns [0, 0, 50, 50], [0, 0, 50, 50]

// shape.getBounds() should return [0, 0, 100, 100]
// shape.getTransformedBounds() should return [0, 0, 50, 50}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what's happen is EaselJS is reusing some rectangle instances to help reduce memory impact. Have a look at the documentation here for more about it:

http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Shape.html#method_getBounds

If you want to force it to give you the originally set bounds you'll either need to `clone` or `copy` them. I've altered your example to show how to output the original bounds using cloning.

http://jsfiddle.net/W9Tb8/2/

```
console.log(shape.getBounds().clone(), shape.getTransformedBounds());
```

Comment: Thank you, Josh! I browsed right over that 'fine print' on the getBounds API!